# interactive window to execute dos commands in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, command-prompt

I know using External Tools options i can run a batch script or a cmd prompt. But here is what i need to do

I want to be able to call a dos prompt inside visual studio, which must be interactive. That way i won't be outside visual studio and can run all my dos commands in it. Is it possible? Or can i extend the command window and capture the commands which are typed and process them using my custom code?

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

There's the [Tools.Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xca6kdd.aspx) command which may work for you. You use the /c switch to specify that the output for the executable is displayed in the Command window. Then you call cmd.exe with /C switch which instructs it to close after finishing the command. For example if you type:

```
Tools.Shell /c cmd.exe /C dir C:
```

This will print the output to the Command window. Unfortunately, unlike the output, the input doesn't work. So if you type:

```
Tools.Shell /c cmd.exe /C pause
```

The prompt will not wait for your input (pressing a key).

If that's OK for you, you can even define an alias for most of this. For example you [define alias](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/excerpt/vshacks_chap1/index.html#visualstudiohks-CHP-6-SECT-4.3) **sh** for **Tools.Shell /c cmd.exe /C**:

```
alias sh Tools.Shell /c cmd.exe /C
```

Then you simply use it as follows:

```
sh dir c:
```

Answer (score 5):

If you install [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/), then it adds Package Manager Console to Visual Studio which is essentially a Powershell command prompt.  There should be ways of doing most DOS stuff via Powershell and heaps more functionality as well.

Comment: You could also look at the code of NuGet and see how to implement this yourself here: http://nuget.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly what you are asking for, but I think you could manage to achieve your goal with StudioShell:

http://studioshell.codeplex.com/

Have to admit that I did not use it so far but it looks very interesting.

Comment: I have looked at it and it seems that is not able to execute DOS commands. What it does is that  it exposes VS automation functionality which would normally require an extension, add-in or package. So this is useful for VS extensions developers. As I'm one of them, I think it will be a quite handy tool for me.

Comment: I think it can do a bit more than that. You basically have power shell embedded and therefore you are quite open what you can do. One video shows mercurial commandlet... thus it should not be too hard to make the DOS commands that you require available for StudioShell.